# Cannot set environmental variable with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

This is the code I am using:

```
DBUSER="testing"
DBNAME="testing"
DBPASS="testing"
export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=postgresql://{$DBUSER}:{$DBPASS}@localhost/{$DBNAME}
```

However when I do "printenv" it doesn't list this variable. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong please?

Comment: Where do you have this code? It works fine to me.

Comment: Are you running this in a script, and then `printenv` when the script exits?

Comment: Unrelated, but I suspect you want `${DBUSER}` instead of `{$DBUSER}`, etc, with the dollar sign on the outside of the braces.

Comment: I have this code in a deployment script and then I run printenv afterwards

Comment: @shellter is that not what I have done though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute your script with     `. ./yourScript.name`     or    `source yourScript.name`

EXAMPLE:

```
cat t
export name=UNIX
./t
echo $name

. ./t 
echo $name
UNIX
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are not global, but per process (and inherited by children).

Variables exported in a script are not available after the script exits.

Instead, you can add the variable to `/etc/profile`, so that it's read and set by each new login shell. Once added, you have to log out and in again to see it (or `source /etc/profile`).